# 22.6 Induced atlas on the boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am trying to understand one step of Loring Tu's (Intro to Manifolds) proof of Problem 22.6.

### Problem

[image]

### Proof (excerpt)

[image]

### Question

I don't understand why (*) is not also true for $j = n$, which would mean $\frac{\partial y_n}{\partial x_n} \vert_{\phi^{-1}(a,0)} = 0$. If it were true, the rest of the proof would not go through, so I'm obviously missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the $n$th partial derivative were also $0$, the upper half-space would map (at least instantaneously) just into the boundary. You would certainly not have a diffeomorphism in that event. Note that ($*$) is derived assuming condition (i), and condition (ii) applies when you're differentiating with respect to $x^n$.

Comment: Thank you Professor Shifrin! This is clear to me now.